# Vim go to next search result and visually select it

Tags: vim, neovim, coc.nvim

So often if I have a code expression like `points.length - 1` and I want to replace it with a variable (for example, named `target_idx` then I'll define the variable:

```
int target_idx = points.length - 1;
```

But now I want to go and replace all instances of `points.length - 1` with `target_idx`. I'm aware I could do `:%s/points.length - 1/target_idx/g`, but I'm not too confident in my regex and don't want to mistakenly replace `points.length - 11` or `points+length - 1` by mistake. (I'm also aware of very magic searching, but also am not super confident about all the subtleties of what it does/doesn't consider special characters)

So what I want is to be able to search for instances matching `points.length - 1` via `/points.length - 1` and then go through the search results with `n`, and then replace the text with `target_idx`.

But because the searched-for text could have spaces or other characters, I can't simply change to the end of the Word `cE` since this would only change `points.length` in my example.

Is there a text motion that goes to the end of the searched-for text?

So I could go

1. `n`
2. `c<special text motion here>`
3. `target_idx`
4. repeat from 1.

I'm using neovim with CoC installed, so am open to more in-depth ideas with plugins or language server replacements, but this feels like it should be a simple text motion that I just don't know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you can go for `gn` (`:help gn` for details). (`gN` searches backward.)

On the other hand, you can give `:s/…/…/` the flag `c` so that it asks you to confirm every substitution (`:help :s_flags` for details).

---

Besides, you could most likely take advantage of `.` to make steps 2 and 3 in one keystroke (`:help .` for details). In your specific example, you'd do this the first time,

<kbd>/</kbd>`points\.length - 1`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>`target_idx`<kbd>Escape</kbd>

and then just keep going to next match via <kbd>n</kbd> and applying the change via <kbd>.</kbd>.

The `:s` solution with `c` flag I mentioned above is faster, as you only press <kbd>y</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd> instead of <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, `gn` was exactly what I was looking for. Although I didn't know about the `c` flag, and will definitely use it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You are halfway there with:

```
:%s/points.length - 1/target_idx/g
```

All you need is the `/c` flag:

```
:%s/points.length - 1/target_idx/gc
```

which tells Vim to ask for confirmation for each substitution.

See `:help :s_flags`.

---

But you might want to look into CoC and the specific language server you use. Maybe they provide higher-level refactoring commands.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `c` flag and it seems really handy